# How to groupby, and have 2 filters and get column value of corresponding filter in a new column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
{
  'id':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4],
  'status':['start','finalized','start','finalized','end','start','s1','s2','finalized','end','start']
  'volume':[2,3,3,4,5,4,5,6,7,8,6]
}
```

I need to group_by **id** and get volume of **'start' and 'finalized'** status of the the **id**.
Basically how do I **groupby** and **filter** to create a new row.

outcome expecting

```
{
  'id':[1,2,3]
  'start_vol':[2,3,4]
  'finalize_vol':[3,4,7]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter and reshape with a `pivot`:

```
(df
 .loc[df['status'].isin(['start', 'finalized'])]
 .pivot('id', 'status', 'volume')
 .dropna()
 .add_suffix('_vol')
 .rename_axis(columns=None)
 .reset_index()
 )
```

Output:

```
   id  finalized_vol  start_vol
0   1              3          2
1   2              4          3
2   3              7          4
```

Comment: this is a good solution except for this issue
what if an id has 2 repeating status 
eg. 
{
  'id':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4],
  'status':['start','finalized','start','finalized',   'finalized','end','start','s1','s2','finalized','end','start'],
  'volume':[2,3,3,4,5,5,4,5,6,7,8,6]
}

Comment: what should be the output in this case? (please add the info in the question)

Comment: let's say the last instance of the repeated status.